# Dynamic casting of Java collection?

Tags: java, generics, collections, casting

```
 public static void raw2generic(List<Object> ls, Class class)
    {
        //class.cast(ls);
       //List<class> newLs= (List<class>)ls;
    }
```

I want to cast the raw List (ls) of type Class (class)... class could be legacy classes like Integer.class, String.class etc. ls is guaranteed will be filled with elements of type class.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to convert a `List<Object>` to a `List<Integer>`?

Comment: 1) Don't use rawtypes, 2) Generics are erased at runtime, A `List<Integer>` is the same as a `List` at that point, 3) The objects held by a variable are not modified in any way when you cast them (an `Object o = "yolo";` is still a string, `List<Integer> ex = (List<Integer>)(List<?>) someStringList` is still a list of strings), so casting `List<A>` to `List<B>` means that `List<B>` still has `A` objects in it, and _will_ throw a class cast exception on trying to use it.

Comment: Right, to repeat what Rogue said, you "can" do this but it's super unsafe.  If you have legacy code like this it might be better to read each object from the list, cast it and put it in a new list.  At least that way you'll catch errors more quickly.

Comment: @Rogue "casting List<A> to List<B> means that List<B> still has A objects in it" -> this wont happen if a raw list is passed then its assured that it will only contain objects of Class class.

Comment: This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the goal here? What are you trying to *accomplish* in this code? If you want to create method which can accept *any* list maybe you can use generic method like `public static <T> void handleAllLists(List<T> ls){...}`.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl as Rogue mentioned the concerns I think this will help too "List<Object> to a List<class>"

Comment: @DavidJohnson that is simply not true - I could call your method like this: `raw2generic(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), String.class)`, and there wouldn't be a single error until after compiling and running the code. Further, your method name seems to suggest you want to convert some raw type into a generic one - but this idea _doesn't exist_ after the code is compiled. So that just leaves compile time fixes, which means changing code. If you're changing the code to make a raw list generic, why not just use a non-raw list to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following "works" but please heed the warnings in the comments.  It is super dangerous.

```
   public static <T> List<T> raw2generic( List list, Class<T> c ) {
      return (List<T>)list;
   }
```

Note the class type isn't needed, unless you were told to use it and then you probably are expected to actually check the types in the list.

```
   public static <T> List<T> raw2generic( List list ) {
      return (List<T>)list;
   }
```

P.S. `List<Object>` works exactly the same way.  It is super super unsafe though.

```
   public static <T> List<T> raw2generic( List<Object> list ) {
      return (List<T>)list;
   }
```

Comment: This works but can please also share the answer for my modified question?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.  Yes it is possible.  Does "Is is" mean "Is it" or does it mean "It is"?

Comment: Sorry for my typo..just want to know List<Object> to  List<Integer>

Comment: There is no difference, so there is nothing to convert, at least, as far as runtime representation in memory is concerned. Generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination: Once your code is in the form of a class file, __it is gone__. Hence, this isn't so much a conversion as 'how do I tell `javac` to shut up and do what I want it to?' - this answer shows you how, and answer 'List<Object> to List<Integer>' already. I do not understand why you ask in a comment how to do it - just do what this answer tells you to, that's how to do it.

Comment: Note that `List` is not the same as `List<Object>`, especially when generic bounding is concerned (contravariant and covariant bounding, which `List` doesn't have). It behaves akin to a `List<?>` that is mutable.

Comment: A `List<Object>` you can add any object (because everything is an object, and that part of the type system is covariant).  A `List<?>` you can't add anything to, because the type is unknown and therefore no type is safe.  That's actually pretty different imo.

Comment: Hence my mention of it being a _mutable_ `List<?>` ;). `List` vs `List<Object>` vs `List<?>` all have differences (you hit the nail for `<?>` vs `<Object>`), but the difference I was speaking to comes up much more for _passing_ a list around, rather than utilizing it. For example, you cannot pass a `List<String>` to a method accepting a `List<Object>`, but you can pass it to a `List<?>` or `List<? extends Object>`. I assume we both know PECS/bounding, but it's still something that can "gotcha" every now and then.

Comment: Then again, a `List` can be passed to any type (also dangerous!), whereas a `List<?>` can only be passed to `List<?>`